# Angular + .net core application failing with @Injectable

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, angular15

Created a brand new Angular + .net core application through VS2022.
First time running, and all works perfectly.

Added a simple file :-

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
class HeroService { }
```

and we are presented with the following error:-

TS1219  Build:Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning.

we have

```
"experimentalDecorators": true,
```

our tsconfig file :-

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": "./",
"outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
"strict": true,
"noImplicitReturns": true,
"noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
"sourceMap": true,
"declaration": false,
"downlevelIteration": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"allowJs": true,
"moduleResolution": "node",
"importHelpers": true,
"target": "ES2022",
"module": "es2020",
"lib": [
  "es2018",
  "dom"
]
    },

  "angularCompilerOptions": {
"enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
"strictInjectionParameters": true,
"strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
"strictTemplates": true
  }
 }
```

why would we still receive this error?

Comment: did you add it using `ng generate service hero`?

Comment: @Andy i didnt, no. Just did 'Add Type script' - to note. if i remove Injectable, it runs perfectly fine.  As soon as it added, it breaks.  I think its  something to do with how visual studio is building the app,  but i cant figure out the issue...

Comment: remove that file you created, and use the command i posted above and try again. Creating a service is a little more complicated than just adding a TS file. There are other things that need to be wired up. I use the same project in VS2022 and have no issues. Read [this](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt4#create-the-heroservice) for more info.